# Weird response with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, concatenation

i am trying to concatenate values into a string which later is attached to a hidden input.

This is the forach loop:

```
<?php
    $langid     = array();
    $transLang      = '';
    foreach($translator['langs'] as $lang) {

        $curlang    = $lang->term_id;
        $langid[]   = $curlang;
        $transLang  .= '('.$curlang.'), ';

        // for testing
        echo $transLang."<br />";
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedLang" value="<?php echo $transLang; ?>" />
```

.

The langid[] array grabs everything correctly
but $transLang echoed into the input only shows the first value which is: (3),

When i use this line:

```
echo $transLang."<br />";
```

Which i added for testing it echoes:

```
(3),
(3), (10),
(3), (10), (12),
(3), (10), (12), (27),
(3), (10), (12), (27), (19),
(3), (10), (12), (27), (19), (20),
```

The last one is the complete string after the foreach finished runing but the input field value is always only the first run meaning (3),

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run a dummy test. Here is my code

```
<?php

    $a = "";
    $loop = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    foreach($loop as $i){
        $a .= "($i),";
    }


?>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedLang" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
```

and i get the following output

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedLang" value="(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),">
```

OR You ca use an additional `array` to store these `strings` and `echo` the last `index`

So Your code will changed to this one

```
<?php
    $langid     = array();
    $strings    = array();
    $transLang      = '';
    foreach($translator['langs'] as $lang) {

        $curlang    = $lang->term_id;
        $langid[]   = $curlang;
        $transLang  .= '('.$curlang.'), ';
        $strings[] = $transLang;
        // for testing
        //echo $transLang."<br />";
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedLang" value="<?php echo end($strings); ?>" />
```

Both methods I've tested on my dummy values and it's working fine for me.
**Try to use second method first**.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response... i know it should work (my method) but it doesent... why did you wrap the $strings in end() ? shouldnt that just echo the last value? the problem of echoing the array is why i didnt use an array for the value in that input. i need a string there. - anyhow, as i tought there is and should not be any isuse with my foreach. just a weird problem.

Comment: `end()` will get last index data and it will output as string

Answer (score 1):

You can use array implode for that:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: thank k.tarkin... i know that. tought there was something i missed / didnt knew about foreach but i guess its just a wierd issuse. thanks for your help.